# Powershell script to Download Specific folders from Sharepoint

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, download

I've got a script that successfully downloads all the content from a Sharepoint site but would like to change it so that it only downloads the content from certain folders with a specific name.

This is the script i'm using:

```
#Function to Download All Files from a SharePoint Online Folder - Recursively 
Function Download-SPOFolder([Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Folder]$Folder, $DestinationFolder)
{ 
    #Get the Folder's Site Relative URL
    $FolderURL = $Folder.ServerRelativeUrl.Substring($Folder.Context.Web.ServerRelativeUrl.Length)
    $LocalFolder = $DestinationFolder + ($FolderURL -replace "/","\")
    #Create Local Folder, if it doesn't exist
    If (!(Test-Path -Path $LocalFolder)) {
            New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $LocalFolder | Out-Null
            Write-host -f Yellow "Created a New Folder '$LocalFolder'"
    }
           
    #Get all Files from the folder
    $FilesColl = Get-PnPFolderItem -FolderSiteRelativeUrl $FolderURL -ItemType File
    #Iterate through each file and download
    Foreach($File in $FilesColl)
    {
        Get-PnPFile -ServerRelativeUrl $File.ServerRelativeUrl -Path $LocalFolder -FileName $File.Name -AsFile -force
        Write-host -f Green "`tDownloaded File from '$($File.ServerRelativeUrl)'"
    }
    #Get Subfolders of the Folder and call the function recursively
    $SubFolders = Get-PnPFolderItem -FolderSiteRelativeUrl $FolderURL -ItemType Folder
    Foreach ($Folder in $SubFolders | Where {$_.Name -ne "Forms"})
    {
        Download-SPOFolder $Folder $DestinationFolder
    }
} 
 
#Set Parameters
$SiteURL = "https://zietza.sharepoint.com/sites/tm_Finance"
$LibraryURL = "/Shared Documents/Budgets/" #Site Relative URL
$DownloadPath ="C:\Reports\"
 
#Connect to PnP Online
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -UseWebLogin 
 
#Get The Root folder of the Library
$Folder = Get-PnPFolder -Url $LibraryURL
 
#Call the function to download the document library
Download-SPOFolder $Folder $DownloadPath
```

Here is my Sharepoint directory Structure:

```
/Shared Documents/Budgets/
--------------------------
/2022/January/2022-January.xls
/2022/February/2022-February.xls
up to December.
/2023/January/2023-January.xls
/2023/February/2023-February.xls
up to December.
/2024/
/2025/
etc
```

So i;d only like to download the **content** of the **"January"** Folder for each **Year** and end up with **2022-January.xls**, **2023-January.xls**, **2024-January.xls** etc in my Download folder **"C:\Reports"**

I've searched for similar scripts and know it should look something like this:

```
Foreach ($Folder in $SubFolders | Where-Object { $_.Name -like "January*"})
```

but can;t get it to download the content of the folder.

Any help in the right direction is much appreciated.

Cheers,
ZietZa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I would implement your requirements:

```
$LocalFolder = 'C:\Reports'

$UrlSharepoint = 'https://zietza.sharepoint.com'
$UrlSite = '/sites/tm_Finance'
$LibraryFolder = '/Shared Documents/Budgets'

# Connect to Sharepoint and save the connection
$Connection = Connect-PnPOnline -Url "${UrlSharepoint}${UrlSite}" `
                    -Credential $Credential `
                    -ReturnConnection `
                    -ErrorAction Stop
try {
    Get-PnPFolderItem -FolderSiteRelativeUrl $LibraryFolder `
                      -Connection $Connection `
                      -ItemType File `
                      -Recursive | 
        Where-Object {$_.ServerRelativeUrl -like "*/January/*-January.xls" } | 
        Select-Object name, @{
                                name='SiteRelativePath'
                                expr={$_.ServerRelativeUrl.Substring($UrlSite.Length)} 
                            } | 
        ForEach-Object {
            Get-PnPFile -Url $_.SiteRelativePath `
                        -AsFile `
                        -Path $LocalFolder `
                        -Filename $_.name `
                        -Connection $Connection
        }
}
finally {
    # Make sure to disconnect
    Disconnect-PnpOnline -Connection $Connection
}
```

Notes:

- I used the `-Recursive` parameter of `Get-PnPFolderItem` to retrieve all files located in `$LibraryFolder` and its subfolders (easier than having to recurse down folders yourself, and saves on back-and-forth communication between client and server)
- Only files matching the wildcard `*/January/*-January.xls` are retained.
- Files are retrieved and stored directly into the `$LocalFolder`
- I connected with a predefined `$Credential`, but you could use the `-UseWebLogin` parameter instead if you need e.g. 2FA authentication. Just make sure to keep the `-ReturnConnection` parameter.

Comment: Thanks DocZero, i tried your script and it seems to work up to the Get-PnPFile part where it asks for `cmdlet Get-PnPFile at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
Filename:`

Comment: I updated the code and added the `-Filename` parameter, even though the docs state that it's supposed to be optional. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Yep, that's working now. thanks. i added `-Force` so it would overwrite the files.  and to show me some progress added `Write-host -f Green "Downloaded File '$($_.name)'"`